# Gerar PDF por Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

O que estou tentando fazer é que o usuario ao clicar no botão **gerar** de um formulário, gere um  `.pdf` por requisição Ajax, ou seja, tenho três paginas, onde a `Index.php` esta o formulário, o `controller.php` esta o script ajax onde enviar os dados para gerar o .`pdf` na pagina `procTermo.php`. Não sei se isso é possivel ou eu esteje fazendo algo de errado. Obs: Para gerar o `PDF` utilizo o `DOMPDF`.

**index.php**

```
<form id="termo1" action="controller.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Serial:</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="serialTermo1" required/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Objeto:</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="objTermo1"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cleanfix"></div>
                        <center><button class="btn btn-default" name="btnGerar" value="gerar1">Gerar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span></button></center>
                    </div>
```

**controller.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data_to_send = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($_POST);?>');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'procTermo.php', 
        data: data_to_send,
        success: function(data){alert(data);},
        failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }       
}); 
</script>
```

**procTermo.php**

```
switch ($_POST['btnGerar']) {
case 'gerar1':
$content = "
<div id='title'><u><b>Capa Termo</b></u></div></center>
<div id='content'><p><b>Serial</b>: ".$_POST['serialTermo1']."</p><p>
<p><b>OBJETO</b>: ".$_POST['$objTermo1']."</p></div></body></html>
";
    $dompdf->load_html($content);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("saida-termo1.pdf",array("Attachment" => false));
    break;
```

Comment: Faça um teste, no success coloque esse código: var popup= window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + data, '', 'height=650,width=840');

Comment: Ficou assim -> success: function(data){var popup=window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + data, '', 'height=650,width=840');}, ao executar o código é exibido uma pop-up porém vazio. Analisando a requisição com o firebug, aparece status 200 Ok

Comment: a requisição que voce faz para 'procTermo.php' está retornando o stream do pdf?

Comment: Não, a resposta é `Reload the page to get source for:` http://127.0.0.1/Sis/procTermo.php, agora não sei se esta chegando no `procTermo.php` o conteudo do `Ajax`.

Comment: Quando tenho de fazer algo assim, faço o form dar submit com target _blank e na página que recebe o post gero o pdf, uso fpdf.